# Select records based on other column condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a SQL table structure like:

```
ID UID  Name   PId  Date
1   2   Admin   1   2015-04-25 21:10:40.060
3   28  Admin   1   2015-04-25 21:10:53.873
4   3   Viewer  1   2015-04-25 22:49:12.497
5   7   Admin   1   2015-04-25 22:49:34.670
6   28  Admin   2   2015-05-04 10:41:17.000

ID-> autoincrement, UID->UserId, PID-> projectId
```

Here a user can be assigned to one or multiple projects. So, I have user 28 assigned to two projects PID:1 and 2.

I want all the unassigned users to project 2. (i.e my result should contain UID 2, 3 and 7). And for project 1 it would be none.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

This is what I tried:

```
select UId 
from A 
group where PId!=2 by uId having COUNT(*)<2
```

and the data I am getting is:

```
   UID  PID
    2   1
    3   1
    7   1
    28  1
```

The last record UID=28 is unwanted row

Comment: An what have you tried to achieve this? What is the error/non-required output that you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NOT IN` operator in your `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtableName
WHERE UID NOT IN (SELECT UID
                  FROM #test
                  WHERE PID = 2)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cbbbc/3)